# how to get clock ticks for a C++ code block on Linux ? clock() results make no sense.

Tags: c++, linux, time, click, clock

I am trying to test clock ticks of pow().

```
clock_t startTime = clock();
for (int ii = 0 ; ii < moreIter ; ++ii)
{
   for (int i = 0 ; i < totalIte ; ++i)
   P0Table[i] = pow( 1 + baseTable[i] + baseTable1[i]  , expTablr[i]);
}
clock_t endTime = clock();
clock_t powTime = endTime - startTime;
```

If moreIter is 1 and totalIte is 5000 , the powTime is always 0.

I just followed : 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/

why ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The granularity of `clock()` is usually pretty large. Often a millisecond or larger.

Comment: On Linux, use `clock_gettime`, or in a crunch RDTSC.

Comment: cplusplus.com is fairly out-of-date. I prefer en.cppreference.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the C++11 [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) header.

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

auto start = Clock::now();
/* do work */
auto end = Clock::now();

auto timeTaken = end - start;
```

Comment: How to use the C++11 <chrono> header ? My gcc version 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-17) (GCC). thanks !

Comment: I think you need g++ 4.6 at least, maybe even 4.7.

Answer (score 2):

The clock() resolution isn't particularly high, you may need more iterations to get a non-zero result.

On Linux, cpu time is iirc accounted depending on the CONFIG_HZ setting, usually 100-1000 Hz these days. So 1-10 ms resolution is the best you can get.

With clock_gettime(..., CLOCK_MONOTONIC) you can get nanosecond resolution wallclock time, though of course at that kind of resolution you might want to take into account that the call itself takes a bit of time (IIRC around 20 ns last I checked).